# Для чего нужны переменные флаги

Tags: java, логические-выражения

Я только недавно натолкнулся на этот термин, и я не понимаю для чего они нужны и когда использовать.

Пример

```
boolean haveFive = false; // флаг наличия 5ки в массиве

int[] a = new int[10]; // массив из 10 элементов

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a[i] = new Random().nextInt(10); // инициализация массива случайными значениями от 0 до 9
    if (a[i] == 5) { // если в массиве есть 5 устанавливаем флаг в true
        haveFive = true;
    }
}

if (haveFive) {
    // выполняем некоторые действия
}
```

Comment: А можно `haveFive = haveFive || a[i] == 5`. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переменная флаг – это, как правило, переменная логического типа, значение который характеризует состояние некоторого объекта. В примере `haveFive` переменная которая хранит состояние есть ли в массиве пятерка.

Это переменная, которую вы можете использовать для управления потоком функции, позволяя вам проверять определенные условия во время выполнения вашей функции.

```
if (haveFive) { // если в массиве есть пятерка
    // выполняем некоторые действия
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Не очень понятен вопрос, тем не менее попробую ответить в меру своего понимания.

*Флаг* это некая переменная, которая по сути является статусом некоторого объекта/сущности/множества. В классическом варианта *флаг* это булевская переменная, в более расширенном толковании *флаг* может иметь и несколько значений.

В зависимости от значения флага используется ветвление логики программы `if` и/или `switch`

Когда использовать? Флаги используются, когда статус сущности есть некая сложновычисляемая штука, поэтому чтобы зря не тратить каждый раз вычислительные ресурсы удобно запомнить статус сущности в виде флага и дальше использовать в логике программы. Например, в вашем случае то что массив содержит хотя бы одну пятерку - есть флаг.

Answer (score 4):

Не могу не запостить цитату из любимого мною "Чистого кода"

> Аргументы-флаги уродливы. Передача логического значения функции —
>   воистину ужасная привычка. Она немедленно усложняет сигнатуру метода,
>   громко  провозглашая, что функция выполняет более одной операции. При
>   истинном  значении флага выполняется одна операция, а при ложном —
>   другая!  В листинге 3.7 у нас нет выбора, потому что вызывающая
>   сторона уже передает  этот флаг, а я хотел ограничить область
>   переработки границами функции. Тем не  менее вызов метода render(true)
>   откровенно сбивает с толку бедного читателя.  Если навести указатель
>   мыши на вызов и увидеть render (boolean isSuite),   ситуация слегка
>   проясняется, но ненамного. Эту функцию следовало бы разбить на  две:
>   renderForSuiteO и renderForSingleTestO.

Comment: Это не аргумент, простите за каламбур.

Comment: @defaultlocale Вообще вам бы не мне это писать, а Роберту Мартину :)  С точки зрения следования принципам SOLID, в частности его букве S, это очень даже аргумент

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что в примере в вопросе флаг не является аргументом функции. К дяде Бобу претензий нет :)

Comment: @defaultlocale вы совершенно правы. Просто мне показалось, что данный отрывок будет в целом полезен в контексте вопроса

Comment: Я бы конечно поспорил с Робертом Мартином - мне нравится его перфекционизм, но перфекционизм никогда хорошо не заканчивается. Сейчас просто тема *чистого кода* очень модная (или хайповая - как сейчас модно говорить). Уверен, через некоторое время все забудут эту концепцию :)

Comment: @Barmaley книга 2002 года, концепция до сих пор жива :) Эта книга не столько про программирование, сколько про культуру и гигиену - такие концепции более менее долгоживущие.

Comment: @rjhdby знаете сколько таких гигиенических прокладок - тьфу концепций я уже видел, книга может быть хоть 19-го века, это сути дела не меняет - теперь это хайп, любой подросток к месту и не к месту цитирует эту книжку. А вот как напишет кодик на пару сотен тыщ строк - я посмотрю на его гигиену после этого. Все дело в том, что концепции хороши, пока их не начинают применять в реальной жизни - почему то так получается (зачастую) что грязный код работает намного эффективнее. Вы смотрели когда-нибудь исходники реальной успешной игры? Ну например тот же Doom/Quake - там просто ужас :)

Comment: @Barmaley был у меня личный проект на ~18 тыщ строк. Пройдясь по нему Мартином я его сократил до 15.000 и, самое главное, начал в нем ориентироваться :) Понимание того, что и как в нем работает повысилось в разы. Считаю, что оно того однозначно стоило. (хотя времени потратил конечно). По поводу реального кода тоже опыт есть. Пришлось как-то возиться с одним проектом C-шным. Всего-то 1700 строк кода. Это было похоже на работу сапера со сломанным миноискателем. Пока не отрефакторил - вообще было непонятно как оно работает. (а так то я и asm под радиоРК умею(л), так что не пугайте :)

Comment: Да я же не против. Я просто против абсолютизации концепции

Answer (score 1):

Ну то что переменная-флаг нужна для хранения некоторого булевого результата (в данном случае будет ли в массиве хотя бы одна пятерка) вам уже написали, но надо заметить, что очень часто (и в данном случае) переменная-флаг не нужна, так как можно просто вынести функцию (и это будет работать быстрее):

```
  ...
  if(isHaveFive()) {
     // выполняем некоторые действия
  }
}

private static boolean isHaveFive() {

    int[] a = new int[10]; // массив из 10 элементов

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a[i] = new Random().nextInt(10); // инициализация массива случайными значениями от 0 до 9
        if (a[i] == 5) { // если в массиве есть 5 устанавливаем флаг в true
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Я бы назвал метод containsFive() )))

Comment: Массив внутри метода генерировать не имеет смысла. Либо передать его в метод, что-то вроде `contains(int[] array, int value)` либо просто сгенерировать 10 чисел подряд.

Comment: Да, просто не стал исправлять, чтобы было понятнее. Метод contains(int[] array, int value) не имеет смысла, так как есть ArrayUtils.contains из  Apache Commons Lang.

Comment: Вообще по уму, там можно написать в функции что-то вроде `new Random().ints(0, 10).anyMatch(e -> e == 5);` и всех делов, но это садизм предлагать такое новичку.